# Extract coefficients from penalized regression

Tags: r, regression

I am using the sparse group lasso, which is a penalized regression. The package I am using is SGL. I tried to run the examples in my R, and the code is given as below

```
set.seed(1)
n = 50; p = 100; size.groups = 10
index <- ceiling(1:p / size.groups)
X = matrix(rnorm(n * p), ncol = p, nrow = n)
beta = (-2:2)
y = X[,1:5] %*% beta + 0.1*rnorm(n)
data = list(x = X, y = y)
cvFit = cvSGL(data, index, type = "linear")
```

I tried to extract the regression coefficient of `cvFit`, but it turns out to be

```
coef(cvFit)
NULL
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See `str(cfFit)` and determine the exact location of the coefficients.

Comment: @ Roman Luštrik what do you mean by determining the exact location of the coefficients?

Comment: Not familiar with this function but by typing `cvFit` you can see what values can be extracted. ie `cvFit$fit$beta` or `cvFit$lambdas`

Comment: `cvFit$fit$beta` contains a matrix of coefficients, one column for each `lambda` in the regularization path.

Comment: Post output of `str` function and I'll show you how to access the output.

Answer (score 0):

This extracts the coefficients from the model with the minimum lambda value.

```
coef(fit,s=cvfit$lambda.min)
```